# Cannot access value through keys in nsdictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, key-value

I am confused what problem is this, my dictionary is:

```
eventDetails = (WebHandler.sharedInstance.eventsDictionary?.copy())! as! NSDictionary


print("Printing eventdeatails: '\(eventDetails)'")

Printing event details: '{
    0 =     {
        "_id" = 5661958b2c0fee491a9e9e08;
        date = "9am - 1pm";
        degree = ee;
        eventCategory = sports;
        eventDescription = "cricket match between east and west wing";
        eventPhoto = "";
        eventTitle = "cricket match";
        location = "west wing hall";
        society = "the society that has nothing better to do";
        universityId = ucf;
    };
    3 =     {
        "_id" = 5661981b69439a6a1b17870e;
        date = "8am - 3pm";
        degree = ee;
        eventCategory = sports;
        eventDescription = "football match between batch 13 and 14";
        eventPhoto = "";
        eventTitle = "football match";
        location = "west wing hall";
        society = "King KOng";
        universityId = ucf;
    };
    1 =     {
        "_id" = 566195a72c0fee491a9e9e09;
        date = "8am - 3pm";
        degree = ee;
        eventCategory = sports;
        eventDescription = "football match between batch 13 and 14";
        eventPhoto = "";
        eventTitle = "football match";
        location = "west wing hall";
        society = "King KOng";
        universityId = ucf;
    };
    2 =     {
        "_id" = 566195b12c0fee491a9e9e0a;
        date = "8am - 3pm";
        degree = ee;
        eventCategory = entertainment;
        eventDescription = "showing the harry potter!";
        eventPhoto = "";
        eventTitle = "movie showing";
        location = "west wing hall";
        society = "the society that has nothing better to do";
        universityId = ucf;
    };
}'
```

This is how i am getting it from my web handler class. I have set very simple keys 0, 1 , 2, ... just to get easily whenever it is required.
it is printing complete dictionary correctly but whenever i try to access the value it is letting me get those particular values instead i get 'nil'
The structure is i have dict with dict What i have tried uptil now is

```
let key = "2"
print(eventDetails[key]!) //not working

print(eventDetails["2"]!) // just for confirmation, not working

print(eventDetails["2"]!["_id"]!) // not working
print(eventDetails.valueForKey(idnumber)) // i have doubt on word "key" so i changed it and observed it but not good for me
```

Please help me suggest me some good read or something where i could find the basics or give me some way out. I am clueless at the moment.
Thanking in advance!

Comment: have you tried `print(eventDetails[2]!)` ?

Comment: as @setonugroho pointed "2" is different from 2.

Comment: Can you log all keys and values from eventDetails?

Comment: thank you very much actually i had a thought that key is type of String i even didnt thought of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dictionary is keyed by integer values, therefore you have to access the dictionary with keys of type NSInteger (or Int). Try:

```
let key = 2
print(eventDetails[key]!)
print(eventDetails[2]!)
```